# PHP / Apache how to set session.cookie_domain from outside php.ini

Tags: apache, .htaccess, php, httpd.conf

I need to restrict cookies to my www subdomain, this works by me adding the line session.cookie_domain = www.example.com in the php.ini file. However I have a number of virtual hosts on my server so I need this domain to be different for each one. After a bit of a web-seach, I have tried using:

```
'SetEnv session.cookie_domain www.example.com' - in my httpd.conf
'php_flag session.cookie_domain www.example.com' in .htaccess
```

However both seem to stop cookies working all together!

Any help much appreciated!

Stu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is to use [`session_set_cookie_params()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) instead of setting it via `.htaccess` (the `.htaccess` method only works if PHP is used as a module). You can use it in the following way:

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', 'www.example.com');
session_start();
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `php_flag` is actually meant only for Boolean values. So when using the `php_flag` command, you're actually setting `cookie_domain` to `0`, which is why it stops working.

For text values, you need to use `php_value` in the .htaccess or apache config. Also quoting the value is recommended:

```
php_value session.cookie_domain ".domain.com"
```

see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use [ini_set](http://ie.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) :

`ini_set("session.cookie_domain", "www.example.com");`

Answer (score 0):

In my case this one worked for me:

```
setcookie("name", $Value4Name, time()+$3600 , "/", ".domain.com");
```

But this is for you to record a cookie for the root of the domain.

cheers
PC

Answer (score 0):

This code 100% work, set this code in file .htaccess

```
php_value session.cookie_path "/"
php_value session.cookie_domain ".localhost"
```

Or code for file JavaScript

```
function my_cookie($name, $value, $expires = 0) {
    return setcookie($name, $value, $expires, '/', 'example.com', ...);
}
```